# Using one tag css styles for other tag?

Tags: html, css, xml, odoo

Is it possible to use one tag's styles for other tag as it would be that tag? I mean I have two tags: `button` and `input`. Both have different css styles. I need to use `input` tag, but use all styles from 'button' styles, so input tag would look the same as button. And I only need it for one `input` tag, so I don't want to change current styles.

The reason I need this, because I need to use `onclick` element, and on `button` tag it does not seem to work (at least in openerp framework), but it works on `input`, tag. But both tags look different, so when I add `input` next to `button` tags, it does not look good.

For example (it is done in xml):

```
<button/>
<button/>
<input type="button" class="button"/> <!-- I just written button in class element, so it would show that it would use all button styles and overwrite itself styles -->
```

Comment: A framework that makes it impossible to handle a click on a generic `<button>` element is a shoddy framework indeed. Are you sure you're not just doing it wrong?

Comment: To apply the button styles just to the text elements which are after button, you can use `button + input[type="text"]` or `button + .button`.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol it's possible that I might be doing something wrong. I tried this: `<button name="dummy_print", string="Print", onclick="window.print()" type="object"/>`. Then created method `dummy_print` to only return True as that button requires some method. But it does not do anything with `onclick`. I forgot to add xml, as it is done in xml not html, so I'll update question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two classes:

One for your button

```
<button class="btn">...</button>
```

And the other one for your input

```
<input class="input" />
```

When you want to change the style between two elements, you just change their classes:

```
$('button').removeClass('btn');
$('button').addClass('input');
$('input').removeClass('input');
$('input').addClass('btn');
```

And it will be ok.